# mounting a network server on ubuntu machine

Tags: server, mount

I am using UBUNTU 14.04 and I changed it to exactly look like 10.04. Found it much easier than current GUI of 14.04. I want to mount a network server(a cluster UNIVA GRID ENGINE) on my local machine so I went to Places section and clicked Connect to server, enter the server address and then it got connected. Under Places, there is a Network part where my mounted cluster is present and I can see it mounted(GUI). I have 2 question's as of now.

1. I still haven't mounted it so as to access it from command line. Is this right?
2. If yes for the question 1 , then I installed cifs and use

   sudo mount -t cifs server-name /home/user/Desktop/New -o username=XXX

when i navigate to `/home/user/Desktop/New`  then if i want to use wget to download something it asks for root permission. Why is it so

Comment: I don't think you really have a problem here. Root is probably needed because you're downloading something to/from a remote host.

Comment: Follow the same steps on MAC, does not require root permissions. Why so??

Comment: Mac and Ubuntu are _barely_ similar. Mac is loosely based on Unix, while Ubuntu is a modified Linux, which is based on Unix. It's like asking why cousins or siblings don't behave the same way.

Comment: I have no issues downloading with wget using sudo but, lets say I have a GUI such as IGV which requires a genome to be loaded. If I want to launch that local IGV from my machine and load the genome file present on the mounted server, it does not allow it. In MAC no such issues, that's why I am asking is there a way for permissions to be changed

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 2, try this, it will set your local user as owner of those files:

```
sudo mount -t cifs server-name /home/user/Desktop/New -O username=XXX,uid=yourlocalusername
```

More on this here: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Mounting_samba_shares_from_a_unix_client

Comment: I tried that and it gave me this

[mount: only root can do that]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the sudo command, I edited the answer.

Comment: Hi Jakob
You have to change it to **-o username** and it works. This is because if I use caps it  says enter root password of the mounted server
Some thing like this:
Password for root@//server/users: 
which is definitely not me

Comment: Now let me see whether IGV works the way I wanted it to work and I will let you know